# How to obtain 'su' password in Lubuntu and gain admin rights?

Tags: su, lubuntu

I own a dell laptop configured with **Win-10 Home Edition**. For some project, I had to **live boot Lubuntu v17.10.1** on it.

The issue is - while trying to get access to **'su account'** I am **unable to bypass it**. It asks for a password, which I have no clue where to find.

I tried using the command -  **passwd Lubuntu**, but it changed password of something else, and not 'su'.

How can I obtain password of 'su'?

Comment: In this case, use `sudo passwd` to set the root password if you really need to, but you should execute most commands that need superuser privilege with `sudo`.

Comment: thanks @WeijunZhou, it worked. :) Also, will this technique of putting 'sudo' work for every command?

Comment: Not really by literally putting it before every command. You need to do a little bit work if you have redirections, but generally you can always achieve the goal with `sudo` without explicitly invoking `su`. If you need something similar to `su`, you can just do `sudo -i`.

Comment: ok. thanks @WeijunZhou will keep this point in mind and will see its practical implication as well to better understand it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @WeijunZhou: It would probably be better to post answer as answers, rather than comments.

Comment: @dhag, I am not sure that the solution will work as there were not enough information from the question when I wrote that comment. I can write an answer now however.

Comment: `sudo -s` will give you a shell

Comment: @WeijunZhou: Ah, that makes sense :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu assumes that the user should use `sudo` instead of `su` by default in their live images as well as their default installation. You can use `sudo` to do most tasks that can be done by `su`, but if you really need to change the superuser password, you can do

```
sudo passwd
```

This will prompt you for the new superuser password and you can set it. You can then use `su` as usual.

Alternatively, you can obtain a login shell by `sudo -i`, or a shell by `sudo -s`. Both of which give you a shell with superuser privilege. As for the difference between `-i` and `-s`, check the manpages.

Comment: Thanks a lot #WeijunZhou, #dhag and #AntonyGibbs for your responses. I have marked the right answer and the issue is resolved. Thanks for your assistance.